# Explain about hunspell token filter in elasticsearch with an example

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi i am new in elasticsearch.  i could not able to understand hunspell filter in elastic search website.I need full explanation hunspell filter with clear example.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-hunspell-tokenfilter.html

Thanks
Kumar K.

Comment: Hunspell filter or analyzer ? Paste the link here

Answer (score 2):

Stemming is the process where you convert a word into into its base form.
For eg:

```
[ jumping , jumps , jumped ] => jump
[ running , ran ] => run
```

There are 2 ways to tackle this

***Algorithm approach*** - Use an algorithm to do this. But then making a set of rules like "remove ed" or "removed ing" wont exactly work in all cases. And in some vases it might backfire. But then this gives good speed on search side. Porter stem and snowball are some of these algorithms

***Dictionary based*** - Here is where hunspell comes into picture. Hunspell has a dictionary which has mapping between these variants and their base form.It does a lookup on this dictionary to resolve the word. Hence hunspell is very accurate for stemming but slow on search side ,as a lookup is involved.